# How to auto number the problem in solution chapter

Tags: numbering, amsbook

I'm now use LaTex to write a mathematics problem solving book. It has some problems in the end of the chapter, and the last chapter is used to demonstrate the solution. But I don't know how to auto number the solutions for problems through the chapter, like Chapter 4, problem 4.1 (containing the solution)

I use `gsm-l` packages, a derived package of ams.

Here is the MWE

```
 \documentclass{gsm-l}
 \usepackage[papersize={160mm,240mm},inner=20mm, outer=15mm, vmargin=15mm]{geometry}
 \geometry{includeheadfoot}
 \usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
 \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
 \newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
 \numberwithin{problem}{chapter}
 \begin{document}
 \chapter{Introduction}
 \begin{problem}
 This is problem 1.1
 \end{problem}
 \chapter{Key to the exercises}
 I want to know how to auto list the problem number and the solution is behind it, 
 like : 

\noindent \textbf{Problem 1.1} 

The following is solution. 
\end{document}
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Using the simple example given in the [answers package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/answers/answers.pdf), the only thing I did differently was to use the `book` class instead of `article`, and number exercises per chapter with `\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}[chapter]`.

Comment: I think my question is sligtly different, I focus on gsm package only, and looking for the solution inside this package. For Mike Renfro comment, I want to auto number the solution, with the problem number, i.e Problem 4.1. Here is the solution.

Comment: I think, the best thing to do here is for you to provide a MWE.

Comment: Does the answers package not work with the gsm-l class? I don't currently have a copy of the class to verify.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina A MWE is added

Comment: As Mike Renfro mentioned. the answers package can be used: `\documentclass{gsm-l}
\usepackage[papersize={160mm,240mm},inner=20mm, outer=15mm, vmargin=15mm]{geometry}
\geometry{includeheadfoot}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{answers}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\numberwithin{problem}{chapter}

\renewenvironment{Solution}[1]
  {\begin{trivlist}\item\relax \textbf{Solution to #1}}
  {\end{trivlist}}`
 
`

Comment: And then `\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans1]
\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{problem}
This is problem 1.1
  \begin{sol}
  The following is solution. 
  \end{sol}
\end{problem}
 
 \Closesolutionfile{ans}
 \chapter{Key to the exercises}
 I want to know how to auto list the problem number and the solution is behind it, 
 like : 
\input{ans1}
\end{document}`

Comment: Sorry about splitting the code in two comments, but it was too long for just one.

Comment: Or you can use \newcounter{answer}[chapter] and \renewcommand{\theanser}{\thechapter.\arabic{answer}}